# Manipulate data from excel in mule esb

Tags: excel, mule, mule-studio, dataweave

I have an excel with data like

```
Name    Roll_No     Place
Mahesh  112         Hyd
Manish  118         Pune
Somesh  119         Lon
Abc     110         xyz
```

Now if I have a to fetch name of the student based on roll number through Mule. A flowVar in mule will have Roll_No like 112 and the corresponding name would be Mahesh as a result.

I tried the same with DataWeave in the latest mule version. Below is the piece of code.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" xmlns:metadata="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/metadata" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd">
    <flow name="excelcheckFlow">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\rmishra\Desktop\PoCs" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        <logger message="-----------Read the content------#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <dw:transform-message metadata:id="74fc2359-be73-475f-a800-71ab941497ee" doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> {



    Name: payload01.Name,


    Roll_No: payload01.Roll_No,

    Place: payload01.Place
})]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <logger message="-----------#[payload.get(0).Name]-----#[payload.get(1).Name]---------" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

It's throwing an error to me.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Exception stack is:
1. Cannot coerce a :binary to a :array (com.mulesoft.weave.model.values.coercion.exception.UnsupportedTypeCoercionException)
  com.mulesoft.weave.model.values.formatting.ArrayFormatTypeCoercionValue:31 (null)
2. Exception while executing: 
payload map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> {
^
Cannot coerce a :binary to a :array (com.mulesoft.weave.mule.exception.WeaveExecutionException)
  com.mulesoft.weave.mule.WeaveMessageProcessor:124 (null)

Comment: @Oneil: I have put the error trace for you.

Comment: Can you add that to your OP instead of a comment? It's better there, as it helps detail what's going wrong.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Dataweave doesn't support direct conversions from Excel (xls) yet.
So, you have some options here:

1. If you are able to convert/save excel files as .csv format previously, you can use Dataweave with a csv input:

> https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/using-dataweave-in-studio#configuring-the-csv-reader

2. If you are not able to do that, after the file connector use a Java custom transformer to convert the data (with POI library) to java array and then use Dataweave. (Quite complex solution)
3. Use DataMapper to make the transformation (Take into account that DataMapper will be totally deprecated in future versions of Mule, so, when Dataweave have this feature in future versions, you will have to migrate this transformation)

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be down to your logger. Have you tried putting an "Object-String" transform between your Datawieve and your Logger?

Answer (score 0):

I create the custom transformer as Davo suggested, and successfully converted the excel to an ArrayList, then I have to convert the ArrayList to json before passing into dataweave for transformation.

I am new to Java, any comment and suggestion to improve my answer would be greatly appreciated.

```
@Override
public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage muleMessage, String outputEncoding) throws TransformerException 
{

    Map<String,String> keys = new HashMap<>();
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    Map<String,ArrayList<Map<String, String>>> outList = new HashMap<>();
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    try  {

        InputStream inp = (InputStream) muleMessage.getPayload();
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        //Iterate through each rows one by one
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext())
        {
            i++;

            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            //For each row, iterate through all the columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

            if (i == 1)
            {
                j = 0;
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
                {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    keys.put("f"+j, cell.getStringCellValue());
                    j++;
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();

                j = 0;
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
                {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                    String k = keys.get("f"+j);
                    String v = cell.getStringCellValue(); 
                    map.put(k, v);
                    j++;
                }

                list.add(map);
            }
        }

        inp.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

    }

    outList.put("root",list);
    return outList;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel (XLSX files) support for [DataWeave](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave) (the data transformation processor) has been released with the new Anypoint Studio 6.1.2 version w/3.8.2 Runtime.

Please see how to use it here: [Excel format in DataWeave](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-formats#excel)

And the release notes below:
https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/anypoint-studio-6.1-with-3.8.2-runtime-update-site-2-release-notes